# How to create maps?

Tags: java

well, I am a beginner and I am learning to make java games through internet sources, and right now I am stuck at a thing called 'Map' file. I do have a tile map image and I also have a .Map file with all those numbers(found the stuff over internet). I have no idea how the hell did they get those numbers. If I am given a tile map, how do I create my own MAP file?? please help

Comment: There's no standard format, so I recommend looking at the same place where you found the files.

Answer (score 0):

.map is not an issue as you can make the map by a .txt file, this numbers represent the data that describes the map depending on the game developer.

Something like that 011110/100110 where 0 represent a walkable path, 1 a dead end

Comment: but the map contains other numbers too like 12 21 0 0 1 1 0 1 5 6 4 1 1. what do they specify?

Comment: 0,1 was just an example, as in your file those numbers  has its own representation.

Could you give a link for this project or tutorial your are working on.

Comment: finally i got it, its noting except the tile number iin the tile map